# Any ideas to Get Flexslider to close automatically after carrousel cycles once?

Tags: php, jquery, css, flexslider

Im using Flexslider in Drupal 7.  I'd like it to make it cycle once through the slides and then close, preferably smoothly, and for the entire div to dissapear so that the rest of the floated content below would float up.  That's the vision anyway, I have little command of PHP and none of Jquery so am at a loss to get going.  Was thinking that maybe if I could add a style tag to the last slide, could then just css display:none for the Flexslide.  Perhaps there's a feasible PHP/jquery solution? If anyone had some code to contribute, and could specify exactly where to insert it (flexslider.module?), that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Flex slider have lots of Callback events - http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/ chk bottom of the page.

```
// Callback API
start: function(){},            //Callback: function(slider) - Fires when the slider loads the first slide
before: function(){},           //Callback: function(slider) - Fires asynchronously with each slider animation
after: function(){},            //Callback: function(slider) - Fires after each slider animation completes
end: function(){},              //Callback: function(slider) - Fires when the slider reaches the last slide (asynchronous)
added: function(){},            //{NEW} Callback: function(slider) - Fires after a slide is added
removed: function(){}           //{NEW} Callback: function(slider) - Fires after a slide is removed
```

Use end to stop slider

```
$('#slider').flexslider({
   end: function(){
                  $('#slider').remove();
                  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I can now see that this function was designed into Flexslider.  I'm  looking into the specifics of implementing that callback API in Drupal 7. Have been following this forum: https://www.drupal.org/node/1580902 trying to make it work.  Sri or anyone else, would you know the specifics of how to add this into Drupal, which file to use, etc? Also, does Drupal use ('#slider')? Thanks for your response, need some more guidance to make it work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Drupal

Comment: Ok, well thanks for your answer, it does answer the original question.